# How dependency injection is instantiated using Unit of Work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I was looking to implement the Repository pattern with unit of work in my asp.net core 2.0 app. There are not many examples of doing this using the dependency injection (DI) principle being used in .net core. I tried to rewrite [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) found in the docs. I also tried to add async operations where I could.

Now the idea is that the unit of work passes it's own dbcontext to the GenericRepository for each of the entities that is in use. This then makes sure that you ony use one dbcontext even if you work on two entities.

In my controller I fetch some data like this:

```
var model = new IndexViewModel
{
      Companies = await _unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.GetAsync()          
};
```

In my unit of work the dbcontext is being created using DI. Then it creates new instances of the GenericRepository for each entity while it passes it's dbcontext to the genericrepository's contructor:

```
private ApplicationDbContext _context;
private GenericRepository<Company> companyRepository;
private GenericRepository<Person> personRepository;        

public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public GenericRepository<Company> CompanyRepository
{
    get
    {
        if (this.companyRepository == null)
        {
            this.companyRepository = new GenericRepository<Company>(_context);
        }
        return companyRepository;
    }
}

//repeat for Person
```

But I fear the dependency injection will automatically create a new dbcontext for each time I use the GenericRepository.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal ApplicationDbContext _context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
     //...other methods
}
```

I fear this will actually create two contexts. one for each(if two requests are made)? So in reality the dbcontext would be instantiated three times, one in unitofwork then one for each repository?  [Here is a link](https://github.com/BlueMarmalade/WorkHorse) to the app on github. It is working, but I want to understand how this works. Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how you register your `DbContext` and which lifetime you use.

The default overload of `.AddDbContext` will always register the `DbContext` with scoped lifetime. That means it will create one instance per request.

If you make it **transient**, it will create one instance per resolve and **singleton** one instance per application lifetime.

That should be true for most cases.

However, if you have a service which has a higher lifetime than its dependencies (i.e. a singleton and inject a scoped service), then the above is not true and you have to be careful when you design and do your registration and take this into consideration.

Comment: My dbcontext is scoped, the same is my unitofwork in which dbcontext is sent to. What I wonder about is what happens when I create an instance of genericrepository from this same unitofwork class and pass it's dbcontext to the genericrepository contructor? I assume the genericrepository will use the same context and not make a new. But since the genericrepository's contructor takes a dbcontext, i'm worried that the dependency injection for the dbcontext will override this and make a new one. Sorry if this got messy. I appreciate your answer :)

Comment: When you instantiate the generic repository and pass in the db context (which was injected into your UoW), then there is no IoC container involved at all. IoC is no compiler magic, it happens at runtime and never with `new` keyword. As long as you don't `new` your `DbContext`, there won't be a different instance of it

Comment: In retrospect I thought I had used an interface for my GenericRepository and registered it for DI(I did it in my local code, not in the github one). Because I wanted to find out  what happens if a new class is created and you pass in it's contructor the same type that is set to be automatically injected via DI (but it wouldn't really matter normally, but here it was important that the context passed by unit of work was the type that was used).